# How to fix 'render/2 is undefined' error using Bamboo with Phoenix

Tags: email, elixir, phoenix-framework, bamboo

I'm trying to send an email using a html email template with Bamboo (and Amazon SES) for my Phoenix/Elixir application

I've managed to get the email sending successfully using Bamboo's `|> text_body(message)` method. However I now want to be able to send a html template not just a string so I'm trying to use the `render` fn https://hexdocs.pm/bamboo/1.1.0/Bamboo.Phoenix.html#render/3 but I'm experiencing the following error: `function MyApp.HtmlEmailView.render/2 is undefined (module MyApp.HtmlEmailView is not available)`. I get no error about my view when I use the `text_body` fn.

This is my fn:

```
  def send_test_html_email(to_email_address, subject) do
    new_email()
    |> from("myemail@gmail.com")
    |> to(to_email_address)
    |> subject(subject)
    |> render("email.html")
  end
```

and this is the example fn from the docs:

```
  def html_email do
    new_email
    |> render("html_email.html")
  end
```

I can't see any difference and as I mentioned before, the rest of the fn was working fine with `text_body` as the last line instead of `render`.

My expected result is that the email will send without an error. My actual result is the `function MyApp.HtmlEmailView.render/2 is undefined (module MyApp.HtmlEmailView is not available)` error.

Comment: Based on that error message, you have no module called `MyApp.HtmlEmailView`. Can you please double check that there is no typo in the module name, both at the call site and in the definition?

Comment: What is the name of module that implements `send_test_html_email` function, and did you add line `use Bamboo.Phoenix, view: MyApp.HtmlEmailView` in that module? Also, do you have `MyApp.HtmlEmailView` module?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Justin Wood and Milan Jaric for your comments.

I was using: `use Bamboo.Phoenix, view: MyApp.HtmlEmailView` at the top of my module however the error was being caused as `view: MyApp.HtmlEmailView` needed to be `view: MyAppWeb.HtmlEmailView`. This has resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.